How to Loop cluster / ranges horizontal to vertical via vba
Newbie here and would like to get a loop working in Microsoft excel. Basically, to arrange clusters / ranges from horizontal to vertical.  I have tried transpose function but have not been successful to get a code working and it seems most samples are arranging cells. hopefully someone can enlighten me with this. thanks
(B2:C4), (D2:E4), (F2:G4) to be re-arrange (B2:C4), (B5:C7), (B8:C10)


what do you mean by "arrange"? move the cells? copy contents? what have you tried?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I would like to have a loop to have the ranges from top to bottom.

@DongM "have" is not an action, please be specific what you'd like to do with those ranges. Also posting code you've tried would help a lot.

@MátéJuhász trying to loop by copy and paste each ranges currently horizontal (left to right) changing it to vertical (top to bottom). My apologies for not making this clear as its my first post. I would like to loop copy and paste to have the ranges from top to bottom. I can only make the next range but does not continue.

Private Sub Loop()
Dim e As Double,   Dim loopNum As Double
numRows = Selection.Rows.Count
numColumns = Selection.Columns.Count
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
loopNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets(1).Range("K27:AD27"), ">0")
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:C4").Select
For e = 1 To loopNum
Selection.Offset(0, 2).Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next e
End Sub

@MátéJuhász the ranges can change in numbers and sizes but each ranges will have similar number of cells.

please edit your question instead of adding multiple lines of code in a comment

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.cut

you can use something like this:
Sub move_cells()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("d2:e4").Cut .Range("b5")
        .Range("f2:g5").Cut .Range("b8")
    End With
End Sub

